# How to unit test a LWC component with @api fields

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lwc-jest

How can I use Jest to test a LWC component where data is provided via @api annotation? 
For example, I have a component `unitTestComponent.js`

```js
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class UnitTestComponent extends LightningElement {
    @api apiField;

    connectedCallback(){
        console.log(this.apiField.Name);

    }
}
```

Which I can use it like this

```
<c-unit-test-component api-field={testPayload}></c-unit-test-component>
```

Where `testPayload` is some JSON object, for example `{Name: 'xxx'}` 
Now, I'm trying to write a sample test

```js
import { createElement } from 'lwc';
import UnitTestComponent from 'c/unitTestComponent';

describe('c-unit-test-component', () => {
    afterEach(() => {
        while (document.body.firstChild) {
            document.body.removeChild(document.body.firstChild);
        }
    });

    test('initialization', () => {
        const element = createElement('c-unit-test-component', {
            is: UnitTestComponent
        });
        document.body.appendChild(element);
        expect(1).toBe(1);
    });
});
```

This gives me an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined`.
How can I provide some mock data in the test block?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would provide the value yourself or else it'll be undefined.

```
test('initialization', () => {
        const element = createElement('c-unit-test-component', {
            is: UnitTestComponent
        });
        <!-- set @api variable -->
        element.apiField = {Name: 'test'}
        document.body.appendChild(element);

        return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
           <!-- do your assertion / expect -->
       });

    });
```